# How can I override strict JSON parsing in jQuery's .ajax() method?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

As of jQuery 1.9, if you specify `dataType: json` in a call to `.ajax` but the response body cannot be successfully parsed as JSON, the request will silently fail:

> The JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown. As of jQuery 1.9, an empty response is also rejected; the server should return a response of null or {} instead.

In other words, even if the server returns a success code, jQuery will still consider the request "failed" if the response does not contain valid JSON.  As such, it will resolve the `.fail()` callback rather than the `.done()` callback.

How can I override this behavior, so that jQuery will interpret the request as a success (and call `.done()`), even if it cannot parse the response body correctly?

Comment: That's easy, if it's not valid JSON you shouldn't tell `$.ajax` that you're expecting valid JSON.

Comment: @adeneo Unfortunately, `.ajax` does not provide any sort of built-in graceful fallback mechanism (i.e., I prefer valid JSON, but if that is not available, I'll take what I can get).

Comment: use plain text and parse it yourself. Or, fix the server. An endpoint returning either json or text without input from client depicting which should be returned is broken.

Comment: @KevinB you're seriously downvoting this question just because of how _you_ think it should be done?  This is a perfectly legitimate question.

Comment: I don't disagree that it is a legitimate question, if i did i would have cast a close vote.

Comment: The reason I posted this - _and answered my own question_ - was because this is a significant problem that I'm sure a lot of people would like to know how to solve.  Just saying "fix the server" is not acceptable in a lot of use cases.

Comment: the dataType property accepts multiple values separated by spaces as of version 1.5, and hints at the idea of `jsonp xml` first trying to convert jsonp to xml, and then if failing, converts the jsonp to text and then xml.  that if failing portion leads me to believe that there may be some other way you could solve this without the need of a custom converter, but the documentation is a bit unclear on this topic

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146797/discussion-between-alexw-and-kevin-b).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON parsers that `.ajax` uses (both the built-in browser parser, and jQuery's parser) will [throw an exception](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) if they cannot parse the response.  This exception is what is triggering `.fail()`.

To override this behavior, you need to define a [custom converter](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to catch this exception when processing the response that you're expecting as JSON:

```
$.ajax({
    // We're expecting a JSON response...
    dataType: 'json',

    // ...but we need to override jQuery's strict JSON parsing
    converters: {
        'text json': function(result) {
            try {
                // First try to use native browser parsing
                if (typeof JSON === 'object' && typeof JSON.parse === 'function') {
                    return JSON.parse(result);
                } else {
                    // Fallback to jQuery's parser
                    return $.parseJSON(result);
                }
            } catch (e) {
               // Whatever you want as your alternative behavior, goes here.
               // In this example, we send a warning to the console and return 
               // an empty JS object.
               console.log("Warning: Could not parse expected JSON response.");
               return {};
            }
        }
    },

    ...
```

Answer (score -2):

Don't use `dataType: 'json'`. Use `dataType: 'text'` and call `JSON.parse()` explicitly in your `success:` or `.done()` callback. You can wrap this in `try/except` to catch the error if the JSON is invalid.

If you need to send `Accept: application/json` without this option, try using:

```
headers: { Accept: 'application/json' }
```

or

```
beforeSend: function(jqXHR, options) {
    jqXHR.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that now you've turned two cases into three: `.fail` because of malformed response code, `.fail` because of a 4xx/5xx error code, or `.done`.  With my approach, you know that a `.fail` means that an error code was received from the server.

Comment: No, the exact opposite. WIth my method, `.fail` means only that there was a protocol error (e.g. timeout or 4xx/5xx response code), it doesn't include malformed JSON.

Comment: Fair enough, but in my use case I need to set `dataType: 'json'`, because this affects the `Accepts` header that is sent to the server.  In my use case, the server _might_ use the `Accepts` header to decide what type of content to return.

Comment: Why is your server returning invalid JSON in the first place?

Comment: That's not your concern.  You're the client-sided app, and I expect you to be robust to this condition :-P

Comment: If you need to send a specific `Accept` header, maybe you can do it with the `headers:` option or in a `beforeSend:` function.